# Why do I have to double escape a specific character in sed?

Tags: sed

This is just a testfile to show the issue. The original part looks like that:

```
arch systemd[908]:
```

Now I can replace the closing bracket with a ":" character

```
krys@archeos:~/test]$ cat jctl.log | cut -d " " -f 4,5 | head | sed s/]/:/g
arch systemd[908::
```

When I try to replace the opening bracket it does not work:

```
krys@archeos:~/test]$ cat jctl.log | cut -d " " -f 4,5 | head | sed s/[/:/g
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

I then escaped the "[" with 1 \ character and it still does not work

```
krys@archeos:~/test]$ cat jctl.log | cut -d " " -f 4,5 | head | sed s/[/:/g
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

With 2 "\" it works:

```
krys@archeos:~/test]$ cat jctl.log | cut -d " " -f 4,5 | head | sed s/\\[/:/g
arch systemd:908]:
```

So here are my questions:

- Why does it work with the closing bracket but not with the opening bracket? Whats exactly different in how sed or the bash reads this?
- Why is it necessary to double escape the opening bracket while it works absolutely fine with the closing bracket without escaping it at all?

I just want to understand this. I know how to do this now but I am not satisfied to not knowing the details of this.

Comment: Did you forget to show the output of escaping with a single slash? You have repeated the unescaped one (`sed s/]/:/g`) twice. Also, for future reference, the `cat` isn't needed there, you can simply do `cut -d " " -f 4,5 jctl.log | sed ...`.

Comment: Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and use http://shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are not quoting your sed expressions (bad idea, get into the habit of putting your `sed` commands in single quotes). The reason you need to escape the `[` is because `[` has a special meaning in regular expressions where it opens a character class (e.g. `[abc]` would match one of `a`, `b`, or `c`). You don't need to escape the `]` because sed is smart enough to know that in this case, `]` isn't closing a character class because there was no preceding `[` to close.

Now, because you're not quoting the sed expression, that means that the shell will try to interpret it *before* passing it to `sed`. Therefore, the shell sees your `\[`, and consumes the escape to pass it unescaped to sed. You can see this in action with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ sed s/\[/:/g jctl.log
+ sed 's/[/:/g' jctl.log
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

As you can see, the command actually being run is `sed 's/[/:/g' jctl.log` and not `sed 's/\[/:/g' jctl.log`: the shell has consumed the escape. This then fails because sed is looking for a closing `]`, doesn't find one, so treats the entire string `/:/g` as the contents of a character class, and therefore fails because it can't find the end of the `s///` command.

Adding a second level of escape allows the shell to consume one, and then still pass the `[` escaped to sed:

```
$ sed s/\\[/:/g jctl.log
+ sed 's/\[/:/g' jctl.log
arch systemd:908]:
```

You can see in the output above that sed is given `\[` now and not `[`.

All of these problems go away if you just always quote your sed commands:

```
$ sed 's/\[/:/g' jctl.log
arch systemd:908]:
```

Comment: Also (but unrelated), `sed 's/\[/:/g'` is better written `sed 'y/[/:/'` or just `tr '[' ':'`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I suspect the OP most likely wants just `sed 's/\[/:/'` without the `g`.